# how to reset canvas object height based on the content height?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

[image]I m drawing text content on the canvas which is dynamically generated but I cant able to estimate the height the content occupies within the canvas as resetting the canvas height will reset the canvas. How can I resize the canvas based on the height of the content it draws so that the content is accumulated exactly.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Comment: @WiktorZychla actually I have multiple lines of text along with rectangles please check the image attached , and measure text only gvies width of the text

Answer (score 0):

Presenting complex tabular  text as an inaccesible canvas image is a terrible usability mistake. However if you must you can use the table as an image. You can get the with and height of the image and set the size of your canvas. Finaly you draw the image on the canvas.

```js
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = whatever;
    img.onload = function() { 
    //get the with and height of the image
    var w = img.width;
    var h = img.height; 

    // set the canvas width and height
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height= h;
    // draw the image
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, w, h );
```